# Error when configuring Shared Store for High Availability for Red Hat AMQ (ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0)

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to configure two brokers on two different virtual machines. I would like to get an effect like the picture below.

[image: Shared Store for High Availability Diagram Picture]

- VM IP Address: `10.0.2.15`
- VM2 IP Address: `10.0.2.4`

I currently have an NFS drive already created on the first machine:
[image: NFS Share Drive Proof Picture]

In the documentation from Red Hat I read that to get high availability with storage you need to configure a cluster:
[image: Red Hat HA Prerequisites Picture]

I will make the configurations for my two brokers available below:

Broker 1 (Master):

```xml
<name>Broker Master</name>
<persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
<!--
 It is recommended to keep this value as 1, maximizing the number of records stored about redeliveries.
           However if you must preserve state of individual redeliveries, you may increase this value or set it to -1 (infinite). 
-->
<max-redelivery-records>1</max-redelivery-records>
<!--
 this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       
-->
<journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
<paging-directory>/srv/nfs_share/data/paging</paging-directory>
<bindings-directory>/srv/nfs_share/data/bindings</bindings-directory>
<journal-directory>/srv/nfs_share/data/journal</journal-directory>
<large-messages-directory>/srv/nfs_share/data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

...

<connectors>
<!--
 Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications 
-->
<connector name="netty-connector">tcp://10.0.2.15:61616</connector>
<connector name="broker2-connector">tcp://10.0.2.4:61616</connector>
</connectors>

...

<acceptor name="artemis">
tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false
</acceptor>
<!--
 AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.
-->
<acceptor name="amqp">
tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true
</acceptor>
<!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
<acceptor name="stomp">
tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true
</acceptor>
<!--
 HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. 
-->
<acceptor name="hornetq">
tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true
</acceptor>
<!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
<acceptor name="mqtt">
tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true
</acceptor>
</acceptors>
<cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
<cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>
<broadcast-groups>
<broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
<local-bind-address>10.0.2.15</local-bind-address>
<local-bind-port>5432</local-bind-port>
<group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
<group-port>9876</group-port>
<broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
<connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
</broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>
<discovery-groups>
<discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
<local-bind-address>10.0.2.15</local-bind-address>
<group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
<group-port>9876</group-port>
<refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
</discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>
<cluster-connections>
<cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
<connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
<static-connectors>
<connector-ref>broker2-connector</connector-ref>
</static-connectors>
</cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
<ha-policy>
<shared-store>
<master>
<failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
</master>
</shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

Broker 2 (Slave):

```xml
<name>Broker Slave</name>
<persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
<!--
 It is recommended to keep this value as 1, maximizing the number of records stored about redeliveries.
           However if you must preserve state of individual redeliveries, you may increase this value or set it to -1 (infinite). 
-->
<max-redelivery-records>1</max-redelivery-records>
<!--
 this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       
-->
<journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
<paging-directory>/tmp/nfs/data/paging</paging-directory>
<bindings-directory>/tmp/nfs/data/bindings</bindings-directory>
<journal-directory>/tmp/nfs/data/journal</journal-directory>
<large-messages-directory>/tmp/nfs/data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

...

<connectors>
<!--
 Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications 
-->
<connector name="netty-connector">tcp://10.0.2.4:61616</connector>
<connector name="broker1-connector">tcp://10.0.2.15:61616</connector>
</connectors>

...

<acceptor name="artemis">
tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false
</acceptor>
<!--
 AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.
-->
<acceptor name="amqp">
tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true
</acceptor>
<!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
<acceptor name="stomp">
tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true
</acceptor>
<!--
 HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. 
-->
<acceptor name="hornetq">
tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true
</acceptor>
<!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
<acceptor name="mqtt">
tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true
</acceptor>
</acceptors>
<cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
<cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>
<broadcast-groups>
<broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
<local-bind-address>10.0.2.4</local-bind-address>
<local-bind-port>5432</local-bind-port>
<group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
<group-port>9876</group-port>
<broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
<connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
</broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>
<discovery-groups>
<discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
<local-bind-address>10.0.2.4</local-bind-address>
<group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
<group-port>9876</group-port>
<refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
</discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>
<cluster-connections>
<cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
<connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
<static-connectors>
<connector-ref>broker1-connector</connector-ref>
</static-connectors>
</cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
<ha-policy>
<shared-store>
<slave>
<allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
<failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
</slave>
</shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

It looks like the backup (slave) server is working:
[image: Slave Works? - Proof Picture]

**PROBLEM QUESTION**

Shared storage I can see that it works because the files on machine 1 collect, and on the other it does not. When I try to disable the master (VM1), the slave (VM2) only sees that the connection has been broken, but nothing further happens.

[image: Broker 2 Error Picture]

It looks like VM2 is aware of VM1's existence, but yet they are not connected?

After a few minutes have passed, such an error also appears on the broker master (VM1):
[image: Broker1 Error Picture]

Console configuration screenshot:
[image: Console Screenshot]

Could you please help me how to resolve this issue?

I tried various settings of discovering group, broadcasting group and cluster connection but none of it helped

Comment: @JustinBertram Thank you for answer and for editing my post. Ok, so I understand that since I use `static-connectors` I don't need to use `discovery-group` and `broadcast-group` yes? 

If in case I wanted to then these settings apply only in the master, only in one broker yes?

I removed `discovery-group` and `broadcast-group` property, but it still does not work

Comment: @JustinBertram I'm not sure if this information is what you were referring to nfs mount `[root@localhost etc]# exportfs -s`

`/srv/nfs_share/docs  10.0.2.0/24(sync,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,root_squash,no_all_squash)`

`[root@localhost etc]# cat /etc/exports`
`/srv/nfs_share/docs 10.0.2.0/24(rw,sync,no_all_squash,root_squash)`

By saying 'disable the master' I meant that I press CTRL+C. It also then appears that "ActiveMQ stopped".

Comment: @JustinBertram Okay, I found my mistake :D When you mentioned nfs I started checking and when configuring the first broker I did not specify the full path. I mean I specified `/srv/nfs_share` instead of `/srv/nfs_share/docs`. Now the backup server correctly assumes the role of master. However, one more thing puzzles me. When I try to start the master again (the original one with VM1). That instead of shutting down the backup and taking over the master role again, it waits until the backup is shut down. There is an Error - "Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock"

Comment: @JustinBertram It's me again :D Okay, so I did as you said. I checked the documentation you sent regarding NFS Storage requirements [Red Hat AMQ documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq_broker/7.11/html/configuring_amq_broker/setting-up-broker-cluster-configuring#con_br-configuring-nfs-shared-store_configuring). I mounted the drive again on the slave broker with these recommended settings and the error is no longer there :) Thank you for help!

Comment: I modified and compiled my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure the NFS mount is using the configuration recommendations from the [Red Hat AMQ documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq_broker/7.11/html/configuring_amq_broker/setting-up-broker-cluster-configuring#con_br-configuring-nfs-shared-store_configuring).

Keep in mind that the `cluster-connection` is just there for connectivity directly between the brokers so that the primary can inform clients about where to connect in case of a failure. However, the *file lock* on the shared journal ensures that only one broker is active at any point in time, and the locking behavior depends on the NFS configuration.

Lastly, your configuration is a little confusing because both your primary and your backup have `broadcast-group` and `discovery-group` defined, but your `cluster-connection` is using `static-connectors` which means the `broadcast-group` and `discovery-group` aren't being used. You should either remove the superfluous `broadcast-group` and `discovery-group` configurations or actually use the `discovery-group` via `discovery-group-ref` in your `cluster-connection` in lieu of `static-connectors`. In short, since you use `static-connectors` you don't need to use `discovery-group` and `broadcast-group`. Fixing this won't fix your problem, but it will make your configuration less confusing which is important when diagnosing issues.